# How to set user in audit using Revision Listener

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am implementing audits in my application. So far I have been successful in recording the activities and the records in the audit table. The issue is that I am not able to implement the user.
I researched in many places, I know it's simple, maybe I just do not see something, and at this point you can help me.
I am using Hibernate Envers and the Revision Entity class
im using Spring boot.

this is my class that i get user

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    UsuariosService uService;

    @Autowired
     PermissoesPaginasService ppService; 

    @Autowired
    EntidadesAdministradoresService eaService; 

    @Autowired
    UsuariosService usuariosService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/autenticar", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public LoginResponse autenticar(@RequestBody Usuarios usuarios)
            throws ServletException {

        // verifica se foram digitados o login e senha no front end
        if (usuarios.getLogin() == null
                || usuarios.getSenha() == null) {
            throw new  ServletException("Nome ou senha obrigatório");

        }

        // busca no banco de dados
        Usuarios usuariosAutenticado = uService.buscarPorLogin(usuarios.getLogin());


        if (usuariosAutenticado == null) {
            return new LoginResponse("naoEncontrado");
        }


        // compara a senha vinda do banco de dados com a senha vinda da tela
        if (!usuariosAutenticado.getSenha()
                .equals(usuarios.getSenha())) {
            return new LoginResponse("senhaInvalida");
        }

        String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(usuariosAutenticado.getLogin())
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, "digi2fred")
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000)).compact();



        return new LoginResponse(token);
    }


    private class LoginResponse {
        public String token;

        public LoginResponse(String token ) {
            this.token = token;

        }

        public String getToken() {
            return token;
        }

    }
}
```

my class UsuarioRevEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario_rev_entity", schema = "aud")
@RevisionEntity(UsuarioListener.class)
public class UsuarioRevEntity {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @RevisionNumber
        private int id;

        @RevisionTimestamp
        private long timestamp;

        private String usuario;



        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public long getTimestamp() {
            return timestamp;
        }

        public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }

        public String getUsuario() {
            return usuario;
        }

        public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
            this.usuario = usuario;
        }


}
```

and UsuarioListener

```
public class UsuarioListener implements RevisionListener {


    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        UsuarioRevEntity usuarioRevEntity = (UsuarioRevEntity) revisionEntity;

    // i guess that here i need to pass user log.
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is exactly where you have to set user information to be audited. This information can be extracted from `SecurityContextHolder` and how you get `username` depends on your explicit implementation.

```
public class UsuarioListener implements RevisionListener {

    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {

        // Get username from SecurityContextHolder
        // SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String usuario = ...

        UsuarioRevEntity usuarioRevEntity = (UsuarioRevEntity) revisionEntity;
        usuarioRevEntity.setUsuario(usuario);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes.. but to use a  `SecurityContextHolder` i need to impor some library ? This is the part that I can not understand.

Comment: This is a class from Spring Security, where information about current logged in user is being stored. Where do you have username information?

Comment: Fwiw, Hibernate Envers 5.3 will support dependency injection into your revision listener so you'll be able to inject CDI beans and Spring plans to support this injection as of Spring 5.1.

Comment: @lzagkaretos eu não uso a segurança Spring, acabei de passar o nome do usuário por token .. veja a classe `LoginController`

Comment: sorry... I dont use Spring security  i just pass user by token look the class `LoginController`

Comment: As I see, from there you return a JWT token, which in turn should be sent with every subsequent http request back to server from client, right? How do you handle the token in those requests?

Comment: yes you are right, im passing the token by filter registration bean

Comment: @lzagkaretos any sugest to help me  ?

Comment: I would suggest using Spring Security in your project, so as to have a globally user management in application. You can find plenty of related information and articles. Good luck.